# Display Exception Cause

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to get the cause of a throwable to display it in case of an exception:

```
if (throwable instanof MyException)
    //Do something here..
} else if (throwable instanceof Exception) {
    if (throwable.getCause() != null) {
        //Show the cause here ..
        // throwable.getCause().getLocalizedMessage()
    }
}
```

I always get a `null` value for the `Cause` when using `getCause()`while the Expression watcher show that it has a not null value.

[image]

How to get the cause ?

Comment: Try *throwable.getMessage()*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCause` returns `null` if the `cause` and `this` are the same. Here is a snippet from the JDK:

```
public synchronized Throwable getCause() {
    return (cause==this ? null : cause);
}
```

In your case, is the `UsernameNotFoundException` the exception you're looking at?

Comment: Yes. So if the cause is null it means I don't need to go any further .. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. The Apache Commons ExceptionUtils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html provides some nice helper methods for working with exceptions.